# How to find a bounded linear functional which is nonzero at given point without using Hahn-Banach Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed vector space. For any $0\neq x \in X$, there exists
$l \in X^*$ such that $l(x)\neq 0$. This statement can be easily proved based on the Hahn-Banach Theorem. My question is how to prove this without using the theorem.

Here $X^{*}$ means the dual space of $X$. The dual space consists of all bounded linear functionals from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Why do you want to prove it without Hahn-Banach?

Comment: There's a remark in my notes, but I cannot see why.

Answer (score -1):

Take $0 \neq x \in X$ and complement $x$ by a family of vectors $(e_j)_{j \in J}$ to get a basis $(x,(e_j)_{j \in J})$ of $X$. This uses Axiom of choice.

Then define $l(x)=1$ and $l(e_j)=0$ for $j \in J$. $l$ satisfies the requested properties.

Comment: This only works if $X^*$ means the algebraic dual, rather than the continuous dual, which seems unlikely.

Comment: That's right Eric. And I missed the word bounded in the title.

Comment: In French, we usually denote the algebraic dual by $X^*$ and the topological dual by $X^\prime$. Is it also a usual convention in English?

Comment: I don't recall seeing that convention, though I haven't done much reading about contexts where you care about both the algebraic dual and the topological dual.  But it is definitely very common for $X^*$ to denote the topological dual for Banach spaces.